# Можно ли получить id event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В jQuery можно назначать события.
Но если полю `input` назначить 2 разных события `change`, и одно вызывает и должно продолжать вызывать функцию `func1`, то второе событие `change`, вызывающее функцию `func2`, должно вешаться только 1 раз.

То есть событие `change` func2 нужно отключать, если оно уже было повешено, но не отключать событие `func1`.

```
thisDom.bind('change', func1); // нельзя отключать

thisDom.unbind('change', func2);
thisDom.bind('change', func2);

thisDom.unbind('change', func2);
thisDom.bind('change', func2); // func2 должна вызваться только 1 раз
```

Comment: а причем тут `id event` в заголовке вопроса?

Comment: Что значит "назначить 2 разных события `change`"? Элементу можно добавить два обработчика события `change` (например, с помощью `.bind()` или более предпочтительного `.on()`). Вряд ли вы собираетесь создавать события. События опять-таки сами никакие функции не вызывают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jQuery есть метод `one()`, который навешивает на элемент обработчик события, который выполнится один раз. Потом он будет удален. Это относится к **конкретному обработчику**, а не ко всему событию, поэтому другие обработчики останутся целы. Например:

```
function foo1 () { alert("1") };
function foo2 () { alert("2") };

$(input).one('change', foo1); /* alert один раз */
$(input).on("change", foo2);  /* alert каждый раз */
```

Comment: one() использую. Но интересует именно возможность определять конкретное событие. То есть получить некий id(guid) при создании события и затем удалять его по этому id. Или это невозможно специально?

Comment: @manking а событие вы вручную генерируете?

Comment: @Regent 

Естественно автоматически назначаются. Вручную смысла нет вешать так. В принципе on() мне хватает вполне. Но я думал что должна быть возможность такая контролировать события точно, какое куда было назначено.

Comment: @manking однако способ генерации событий вручную существует не просто так. Но да ладно. У "обычного" (не созданного вручную) события нет уникального id. Есть, например, `timestamp` и `currentTarget`. У меня с самого появления вопроса создаётся впечатление, что вы путаете термины "обработчик события" и "событие".

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно сделать глобальную переменную, которую менять после первого вызова `func2`. Все последующие вызовы будут проверять значение переменной и выходить из функции. Т.е. фактически она просто не будет выполняться....

Что-то типа такого:

```
var funcTwoCalled = false;

function func2() {
    if (funcTwoCalled) return false;
    [здесь само содержимое func2]
    funcTwoCalled = true;
}
```

Comment: Так, быть может, достаточно просто использовать [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?

Comment: Класс! @Regent! Век живи - век учись :) Я и не знал об этом `.one()`. Советую оформить этот комментарий, как ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: На здоровье. В jQuery столько всего натолкано, что можно хоть каждый день что-то новое узнавать :) Уже есть такой ответ. И, главное, до сих пор не очень понятно что же на самом деле хочет автор.