# Подсчитать сумму выбранную в селектах

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая табличка, см картинку.
[image: таблица]

Нужно подсчитать полученную сумму услуг в реальном времени, их порядка 50 на странице.
Т.е., например, выбрали диван 2х местный 2 шт и 3 посадочных места дивана, т.е. надо умножить цену услуги на её количество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вариант:

```js
function recalculatePrices() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.service').each(function() {
    total += $(this).val() * $(this).attr('data-price');
  });
  $('#result').html(total);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.service').on('change', recalculatePrices);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-price="5" class="service">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select data-price="3" class="service">
  <option></option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Замечания:

- все списки должны иметь класс `service`. Именно по этому классу потом будет определяться, включать их в расчет стоимости или нет
- у каждого списка должен быть атрибут `data-price`. Именно эта цена будет использована при расчетах
- с помощью метода jQuery `bind` каждому списку присваиваем событие `onChange`, и оно будет запускать функцию перерасчета `recalculatePrices();`

Надеюсь, Вам это подойдет.

Comment: @Regent, спасибо и за правку текста, и комментарии. Все с благодарностью принято. Ответы: Ваш №1 - это не убранный остаток от моих тестов :); №2 - исправлено; №3 - я так понимаю, это замечания к моим текстам, а не к коду?... Пытался попроще написать. По понятнее новичку; №4 - согласен - сделано. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Надеюсь, привношу этим каплю пользу :) По третьему пункту: да, это про использование терминов "событие" и "обработчик события" в тексте.  Я так и не осознал текст [недавнего вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483198/). Например, фразу "назначить 2 разных события `change`".